# How to get tasks filter by processDefinitionId in activiti-rest REST API

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, activiti, business-process-management

I am trying to fetch all tasks having specific processDefinitionId. This is my URL:

http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks?processDefinitionId=reviewSaledLead:1:40

But tasks are not getting filtered by processDefinitionId. Is is giving me all tasks from ACT_RU_TASK table without filtration.

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into it and you are correct: processDefinitionId is not part of that particular REST API, which I think is an oversight.

I've added it in this commit: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/commit/86df130a678154f50e241abfec3f3bd99d3f9e7a. It will be part of the next release of Activiti.

Comment: Thanks Joram Barrez..   :)

Comment: Thanks Joram Barrez.    :)
right now I am hitting REST API to get ProcessInstancesIds with processDefinitionId  url parameter, and then using processInstanceId , Iam fetching tasks records. Is this a correct way to get tasks related to specific processDefinition ? 
like this way-

http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances?processDefinitionId="+processDefID
this will give me list of processInstances.

http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks?processInstanceId="+procesInstId;